# Add product to cart in specific shop in Prestashop 1.6 (programmatically)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a large problem with PrestaShop, I'm using an API created by myself to provide service to a mobile Application.

Now, I can add, delete, update quantity to first shop cart.
I can too navigate to categories and subcategories like my online shop.

But I have two shops and I would like to add a specific product on multishop mode to the second shop, and the script always add to the first shop cart.

This is my line to add in cart.

first shop id = 1
second shop = 4

```
$_shop = new Shop(_PS_SHOP_SELECTED_ID); //_PS_SHOP_SELECTED_ID = 4
$isAdded = $cart->updateQty((int)$product->quantity, (int)$producToAdd->id, $id_product_attribute, FALSE, 'up', 0,$_shop);
```

Comment: How do you create or get the $cart?

Comment: $context = Context::getContext();
  if (!$context->cart->id) {  
    $context->cart->add(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,_PS_SHOP_SELECTED_ID);
    $context->cookie->id_cart = $context->cart->id;
          $cart = new Cart($context->cart->id);
          $cart->id_customer = (int)UserApi::getIdAuthUser();
          $cart->id_lang = _PS_APP_MOBILE_LANG_ID;
          $cart->id_currency = (int)Context::getContext()->currency->id;
          $cart->id_carrier = 1;
          $cart->recyclable = 0;
          $cart->gift = 0;
 }
 $cart = new Cart($context->cart->id);

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add more code?

Comment: Be more precise, for the code step or anything else . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the best and proper way to change shop in context.
I make many searchs from code and i found the first shop assignment is in config.inc.php but steel get the value from Shop class.

So to change the shop in context override:

`Shop::initialize();` in Prestashop Shop class

to set your desire shop !